# How to find the equilibrium constant under non-standard conditions?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy, entropy

> Given the following thermodynamic data at $\pu{298 K}:$
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{lrrr}
> \hline
> \text{Compound} & \Delta_\mathrm{f}H^\circ/\pu{kJ mol^-1} & S^\circ/\pu{J K^-1 mol^-1} & C_p^\circ/\pu{J K^-1 mol^-1}\\
> \hline
> \ce{HI(g)} & 26.5 & 206.6 & 29.2 \\
> \ce{I2(g)} & 62.4 & 260.7 & 36.9 \\
> \ce{H2(g)} & 0.0 & 130.7 & 28.8 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> determine the equilibrium constant $K$ for the following reaction at $\pu{475 K}$ and $\pu{1 bar}:$
>
> $$\ce{I2(g) + H2(g) <=> 2 HI(g)}$$
>
> NB: Do **not** assume that the enthalpy and entropy of reaction are independent of temperature. What assumption(s) **do** you need to make?

At first I thought I could work out the enthalpy change using Kirchhoff’s law of thermochemistry

$$\Delta H(T_2) = \Delta H(T_1) + \int_{T_1}^{T_2}\Delta C_p\,\mathrm dT$$

and then find the entropy change of reaction similarly. Then apply

$$\Delta G = \Delta H - T\,\Delta S$$

and use the equation relating $\Delta G$ and $K,$ but I know that is only for the Gibbs free energy change under standard conditions. The question tells me to assume the enthalpy and entropy depend on temperature, so I’m not sure what my approach should be for this.

Comment: The first statement about $\Delta_rG$ is not correct. It should be correct if $K$ is replaced by $Q$

Comment: Wouldn’t it be -RTlnK+RTlnQ?

Comment: I don't think so. Look ! If $Q$ is approaching $K$, your formula would get $\Delta G = 0$, and $K = 1$.  This is not correct.

Comment: Do you know how to quanify the effect of temperature on the equilibrium constant?

Comment: The Van‘t Hoff equation? Not sure how I should use the Cp

Comment: That's correct.  But first you need to use the Cp's to express the $\Delta H^0$ as a function of temperature.  Then you have to integrate the Van't Hoff equation taking into account the temperature dependent of the $\Delta H^0$.

Comment: That makes sense. So I don’t use the deltaG= deltaH-TdeltaS at all? I don’t need to find the entropy of reaction?

Comment: You need that to get K at 298K.

Comment: Ok. So is the assumption that Cp is independent on temperature? Or is it that deltaH and deltaS only vary slightly with T?

Comment: And is it ok to just substitute the modified deltaH into the already integrated regular form of the Van’t equation?

Comment: They expect you to assume that the heat capacity is independent of temperature, so that $$H^0(T)=H^0(298)+C_p(T-298)$$It isn't OK to use the integrated regular form.  You need to integrate the new version.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for this. Has this been done before so I can check the final form of my integrated expression?

Comment: Have some confidence and integrate it yourself.

Comment: I have certainly given it a go, but I have no idea whether it is right or not

Comment: Using the Gibbs- Helmholtz equation with deltaG(standard)=-RlnK and integrating with the equation with the modified deltaH i end up with the same as I would have gotten had I just substituted it after. Is the T in the (T-298 ) not just a constant and not a variable? It would be the T we are wanting to find the new K at. Sorry I am taking up so much of your time. I really appreciate it

Comment: Ok with a fresh mind I realised what I said was just silly. I integrated properly (i hope) and got K=137. I would write out my full expression but I’m not sure how to do that on here. Does my final answer look right?

Comment: @MarinaCalder You can post an answer to your own question, it's a good practice on SE sites. If you are still having difficulties with formatting and typesetting math, post it the best way you can assure it's readable, and someone will edit it. Also, please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: There should be used the similar integrating formula for temperature dependence on reaction entropy, with the temperature in the integral denominator ( Cp . dT/T = dQ/T = dS ).